# How to create pandas dataframe from my oredered dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

data = OrderedDict([('data(xxx_a1)_first_type', 0.12),
                    ('data(xxx_a2)_first_type', 0.14),
                    ('test(xx_b15)_second_type', 0.15)])
```

How can I get data as follows:

```
type        avg
first_type  0.12
first_type  0.14
second_type 0.15
```

This is what I have to retrieve type values and calculate averages per type. I would like to maintain similar approach to get the expected result:

```
pd.DataFrame([(z, np.mean([y for x,y in v.items() if x.endswith(z)])) for z in ['first_type', 'second_type']], columns=['type', 'avg_val'])
```

Comment: Can you provide a slightly more complete example? Your attempt seems to indicate things might not always end with `first_type` or `second_type` and that you need to take a mean of values, yet your sample data doesn't at all indicate that's necessary. Are there cases like this that need to be handled?

Comment: @ALollz: You can safely assume that things always end with `first_type` and `second_type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to get dict values to a dataframe and then groupby according to type (first_type, second_type etc).If it is like that, my answer is following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = OrderedDict([('data(xxx_a1)_first_type', 0.12),
                    ('data(xxx_a2)_first_type', 0.14),
                    ('test(xx_b15)_second_type', 0.15)])

# Create DataFrame

values = []
keys = list(data.keys())
for key in keys:
    values.append(data[key])
res = pd.DataFrame(keys)
res.columns = ["type"]
res["avg"] = values
```

This returns:

```
    type    avg
0   data(xxx_a1)_first_type 0.12
1   data(xxx_a2)_first_type 0.14
2   test(xx_b15)_second_type    0.15
```

Then `groupby` types:

```
res["type"] = res["type"].str.split(")", expand = True)[1].str[1:]


type    avg
0   first_type  0.12
1   first_type  0.14
2   second_type 0.15

res.groupby("type")["avg"].mean()

type
first_type     0.13
second_type    0.15
Name: avg, dtype: float64
```

Hope it works!

Edit: Creating the dataframe like this is a better approach like @ALollz 
 mentioned

```
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['avg']).reset_index().rename(columns = {"index":"type"})

    type                        avg
0   data(xxx_a1)_first_type     0.12
1   data(xxx_a2)_first_type     0.14
2   test(xx_b15)_second_type    0.15
```

Then you can continue to `split` and `groupby`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

data = OrderedDict([('data(xxx_a1)_first_type', 0.12),
                    ('data(xxx_a2)_first_type', 0.14),
                    ('test(xx_b15)_second_type', 0.15)])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=[0]).T
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['type', 'avg']
df['type'] = df['type'].apply(lambda x: x.split(')')[-1].split('_', 1)[-1])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          type   avg
0   first_type  0.12
1   first_type  0.14
2  second_type  0.15
```